# How to prove kinematics formula $V_{t/2}=\bar{V}=(V_{0}+V_{t})/2$ using calculus?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, calculus

This formula is called as the "mid-moment rule" which is defined as: for objects that move in a uniformly accelerating linear motion, the instantaneous speed at the mid-moment during a certain period of time is equal to the average speed during this period of time:
$$V_{t/2}=\bar{V}=\frac{V_{0}+V_{t}}{2}$$

I know how to prove this rule with algebraic methods but aren't quite sure how to do the same with calculus.

Comment: Just calculate it directly: $v(t_0+\Delta t)=v(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^{t_0+\Delta t}\dot v(t')\mathrm dt'$. With $\Delta t=\frac t2$ you get the formula. It's an immediate application of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an object moving linearly, given acceleration is a constant c,
$$\frac{dv}{dt} = c \implies dv= cdt$$
Now for the time interval ($t_0, t_0 + t$), given initial velocity $v_0$ we integrate over the time interval and since acceleration is constant,
$$v_t = v_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t_0 + t}cdt = v_0 + ct$$
V just has a linear dependence on t. Now let's say you want to find the integral for half the time interval.

$$v_t/2 = v_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t_0 + t/2}cdt = v_0 + ct/2$$

Now using these two equations we can easily find the mid moment rule formula. Note that this wouldn't have been the case if acceleration had time dependence.

Comment: Your answer could be improved if you elaborated a bit on your last sentence, which is an important observation, imho. Both algebraically and with calculus, we just calculate $v(t_0+\Delta t)=v(t_0)+\Delta v$. It's just the method to find $\Delta v$ that's slightly different.